# ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.MediaLibraryService gobbling up disk space

Tags: macos, photos

I was low on disk space, and upon further inspection I discovered `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.MediaLibraryService` taking up over 10GB of space. I was recently downloading syncing my iCloud photos into a photo library, and the files in this cache folder seem to be the files that are being downloaded, albeit with randomized filenames (which may be how they are stored inside the photo library). Is it safe to delete the contents of this folder? I see no reason that they should stay around in my hard drive even though they are being downloaded to a photo library in a different location.